# "You are used to" vs. "you used to use"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

I'm currently reading some boring programming book and have found this phrase:

> If you are used to C and `printf()`, you might think `cout` looks odd.

If I wrote this phrase (supposing I understand it correctly) I would say:

> If you used to use C and ...

without *are* and with additional *use*.

So the question is: why was it written in that way? Is it a short way of writing “used to use” or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first sentence, *If you are used to* means 'If you are familiar with'. In the second, *If you used to use* means 'If you were in the habit of using in the past'.

Comment: Oh, right. Shame on me, just learnt it few days ago

Answer (score 1):

**Used to + verb** means explaining something about the past:

> I used to go to the gym, but now I've no time to do it.

**Be used to + noun** means explaining something that you are familiar with:

> I am used to loud music because I was in a rock band.
>   I am used to working till late.

Comment: Hi Burak, welcome to EL&U. This is a useful contribution, but I've edited your answer to correct the errors in English expression. Note that while we're tolerant of such errors in a question, we expect *answers* on this site to be authoritative and correct; ambiguous, poorly expressed or inaccurate answers tend to be downvoted. You might like to read our guidance on [answer] and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)