# How to use "used to use"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, writing-style

Is it correct to say something like this?

> I used to use the knife to open things like cans.

Comment: Related: [“You are used to” vs. “you used to use”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66880/you-are-used-to-vs-you-used-to-use)

Comment: The unusual pronunciation of *used* when it means *"was accustomed to/was in the habit of"* also arises in [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/) which started off being about **have/haff**. But @RegDwight is too diffident - this is a dup of the one he linked.

Answer (score 10):

It's fine to use that way as far as you maintain that you no longer "open the cans using a knife". Also, "used to" is a modal verb that can be used with any verb and in this case, "use."

Answer (score 7):

Yes, *used to use* is a perfectly normal construction.

Answer (score 5):

That’s fine (as per Barrie and Manoj), but you may want to say *a knife*, unless you always did your opening with a specific knife that’s contextually salient.

On the same theme as your question, you can create other sentences where a verb is used both in its “lexical” and its “grammaticized” senses.  For instance:

1. *I have to have it.* [modal *have* and lexical *have*]
2. *He has to have had it*. [modal *have*, perfect *have*, lexical *have*]
3. *She had me have him over.* [causative *have*, lexical+particle *have*]
4. *Who knows what he will will.* [auxiliary *will*, lexical *will*]
5. *She’s going to go*. [auxiliary *go*, lexical *go*]
6. *Who will they make make a cake.* [causative *make*, light verb *make*]

If you get carried away, you could end up with *Who has she had to have have you over?*

Comment: You left out _do-do_, as in: "Birds don't do that, but they do do this." :^)

Comment: Indeed: _... that dodos do do do-do_.

Comment: I park my car under a tree.  Birds do do do all over it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *used to use* is perfectly normal. I normally pronounce it `uste` instead of `uzed`. Just remember that it also means you don't anymore. "Used to" is a verb and the rest of the sentence is the direct object. I believe it would be a bare infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Manoj and Daniel. If you no longer do something, then it works well to use the phrase as such. Otherwise, watch the flow of sentences and writing because extra tangles of words and clauses can pile up quickly.